# how to insert new line in eclipse using Preference and formatter?

Tags: eclipse, formatting, preferences

I am trying to format my code in a way to leave a line whenever i enter once. I go to `Window->Preferences->Java->Code Styles ->Formatter`  .. Created my own profile . but still can't get a way to format my code in such a way.. I have went through the option but still can't find a way to make my code like this.. assist me in this matter.  Each statement must leave a line when i pressed CTRL+SHIFT+F.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually insert the blank lines where you want them; the formatter has no capability to insert lines between statements.

In your Formatter profile, go to the Blank Lines tab and check the value of **Number of blank lines to preserve**.

[image]

Comment: If you want useful help, you're going to have to provide better information and responses than "not working."